# Apache2.4 Has Stopped Logging Entries

Tags: apache-http-server

I have successfully restarted apache, I ran configtest, I've run apachectl -t and everything says apache is "OK"

However, my error.log has simply stopped logging any new entries for almost 2 hours no matter what changes I make.

Stumped.. help :-/

Comment: Are you sure there are errors to log?

Comment: It was a weird ISPConfig thing... posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my mystery problem is some type of "fail safe" function of ISPConfig. Normally if you configure virtualhost with incorrect Apache Directives you could take down your entire server and all the website functioning on it.

When I made the type "SSLProxyEngine" instead of "SSLProxyEngine On".  ISPConfig saved my other sites by moving the fault vhost to "example.com.vhost.err" in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory and essentially creating a temporary example.com.vhost to keep things running.

The solution was to

1.) rename the example.com.vhost --> example.com.vhost.bak,
2.)correct/fix the example.com.vhost.err by adding the missing "SSLProxtEngine ON", and
3.)renaming example.com.vhost.err --> example.com.vhost
4.) then restarting apache

Not my solution, I got it from th ISPConfig support site.